# Understanding where equation $2.3$ comes from?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, velocity

I'm trying to understand this [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20030912200701id_/http://www34.homepage.villanova.edu:80/robert.jantzen/research/articles/q51010.pdf) (equation $2.3$ specifically):

Bini, D., Carini, P., & Jantzen, R. T. ($1995$). Relative observer kinematics in general relativity. Classical and Quantum Gravity

> It is convenient
> to also introduce the relative boost map $B(u,u')$
> which is an isometry acting non-trivially
> only on the relative observer plane spanned by $u$ and $u'$
> , mapping $u$ onto u and $LRS_{u'}$
> onto $LRS_u$ (acting as the identity on the orthogonal complement of the relative observer
> plane), and satisfying
>
> $$ B(u,u')\nu(u,u') = \gamma(u,u)^{-1} P(u,u') \nu(u,u') = - \nu(u',u) $$

where $u$ is a $4$-velocity, $u'$ is another $4$-velocity, the relative velocity relative velocity $ν(u',u)$ (of $u'$ with respect to $u$), the gamma factor is $\gamma(u',u) = u \cdot u'$, the [projection operator](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Relativity/Book%3A_Special_Relativity_(Crowell)/03%3A_Kinematics/3.07%3A_The_Projection_Operator) is given by $P(u)$, the relative projection operator is given by $P(u,u') = P(u)P(u')$ and $B(u,u')$ is the relative boost map.

How does one derive or cross verify the above equation? In particular:

$$ \gamma(u,u)^{-1} P(u,u') \nu(u,u') = - \nu(u',u) $$

Comment: It might be good to revise the title to refer to a physical concept, rather than to an equation reference in a book (not named in the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me a slight variation in notation:

\begin{align}
u'^a & \stackrel{2.1c}{=} \gamma[u^a+V_{(u',u)}^a]\label{1c}\\
u^a  & \stackrel{2.1d}{=} \gamma[u'^a+V_{(u,u')}^a]\label{1d}
\end{align}

The spatial-projection with respect to $u^a$ is
$$P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \equiv \left( \delta^a{}_b -\sigma u^a u_b\right),$$
where $u^a u_a=(1/\sigma)$.
For Jantzen,
since $u^a u_a=-1$, then $\sigma=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$.
So, one could absorb the signature convention and write
$
P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \stackrel{\tiny (-+++)}{\equiv} (\delta^a{}_b + u^a u_b)
$.

---

Note, from 2.1c:
\begin{align*}
P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b u'^b 
&\stackrel{2.1c}{=} P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b\gamma[u^b+V_{(u',u)}^b]\\
&\stackrel{proj}{=} \gamma[ 0^a+P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b V_{(u',u)}^b]\\
&\stackrel{proj}{=}  \gamma[ 0^a+V_{(u',u)}^a] &\qquad{\mbox{since $P_{(u)}$ is a spatial projection operator}}\\
&= \gamma V_{(u',u)}^a &\qquad(\mbox{Think "$\sinh\theta\ u_{\perp}{}^a$"}) \\
\end{align*}
so that we get (2.2)
\begin{align*}
V_{(u',u)}^a
&\stackrel{proj1c}= \frac{1}{\gamma} P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b u'^b \\
\end{align*}

Similarly, from 2.1d, $P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b u^b = \gamma V_{(u,u')}^a $ so that
\begin{align*}
V_{(u,u')}^a
&\stackrel{proj1d}{=} \frac{1}{\gamma} P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b u^b \\
\end{align*}

---

Recall that $P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b $ is a projection operator.
So,
\begin{align*}
\left(P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b P_{(u')}{}^b{}_c \right)u^c
&= \left( P_{(u')}{}^a{}_c \right) u^c\\
P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b \left(P_{(u')}{}^b{}_c u^c\right)
&= \gamma V_{(u,u')}^a \\
P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b \left( \gamma V_{(u,u')}^b \right)
&= \gamma V_{(u,u')}^a \\
\end{align*}
Thus,
\begin{align*}
P_{(u')}{}^a{}_b \left(  V_{(u,u')}^b \right)
&\stackrel{proj1d}{=}  V_{(u,u')}^a \\
\end{align*}

---

Now, form the relative projection operator:

\begin{align*}
P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_c V_{(u,u')}^c
&\stackrel{def}{=}\left( P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b   P_{(u')}{}^b{}_c\right) V_{(u,u')}^c \\ 
&\stackrel{assoc}{=} P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b  \left(  P_{(u')}{}^b{}_c V_{(u,u')}^c \right)\\ 
&\stackrel{proj1d}{=} 
P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \left( V_{(u,u')}^b \right) 
\\
&\stackrel{2.1d}{=} P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \left( \frac{1}{\gamma}u^b - u'^b \right)
\\
&\stackrel{distrib}{=}
P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \left( \frac{1}{\gamma}u^b \right) - P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b u'^b 
\\
&\stackrel{proj}{=}
0^a-P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b u'^b 
\\
&\stackrel{proj1c}{=}
- \gamma V_{(u',u)}^a
\\
\\
\end{align*}
Thus, we can form the relative boost map $B_{(u,u')}$:
\begin{align*}
 \frac{1}{\gamma} P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_c V_{(u,u')}^c = -V_{(u',u)}^a
\end{align*}

---

I hope I got all of the signs and primes correct. Please check.