# Where does the relative velocity composition law equation come from?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, velocity, relative-motion

I'm trying to understand this [paper](https://web.archive.org/web/20030912200701id_/http://www34.homepage.villanova.edu:80/robert.jantzen/research/articles/q51010.pdf) (equation $2.8$ specifically):

Bini, D., Carini, P., & Jantzen, R. T. ($1995$). Relative observer kinematics in general relativity. Classical and Quantum Gravity

> one wishes to express the relative velocity $\nu(U,u)$ of $U$ with respect to the first
> observer in terms of the one $\nu(U,u')$ with respect to the second observer, and the relative
> velocity $\nu(u',,u)$ or $\nu(u,u')$ between the two observers.

where $u$ is a $4$-velocity, $u'$ is another $4$-velocity, the relative velocity $ν(u',u)$ (of $u'$ with respect to $u$), the gamma factor is $\gamma(u',u) = u \cdot u'$, $P(u)$ is the projection orthogonal to $u$ in each tangent space (spatial projection with respect to $u$) and the relative projection operator is given by $P(u,u') = P(u)P(u')$

How does one derive or cross verify the above equation? In particular:

$$ \nu(U,u') = - [ u \cdot \nu(U,u') + P(u,u') \nu(U,u')]  $$

### My Attempt

From $(2.1c)$ and $(2.1d)$ we have:

$$\frac{U}{\gamma (U,u')} = \gamma(u',u) (u + \nu(u',u)) + \nu(U,u') $$

From a variation of $2.2$ we know:

$$ \frac{P(u')}{\gamma(u',U)} U = \nu(U,u')$$
a
Applying the projector operator $P(u')$:

$$ \nu(U,u') = P(u') \gamma(u',u) (u + \nu(u',u)) + \nu(U,u') $$

which is nothing like their expression.

Comment: You should really define the Projection operator P(u), as I wrote in my answer ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/723077/148184 ) to your previous question https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/722890/ . P(u) is the "spatial projection with respect to u".

Comment: @robphy I actually agree your notation is more convenient. It's just that I'm trying to use the notation as the paper for consistency.

Comment: But you should at least use a more descriptive term. One can have a projection operator that projects the temporal-part and a complementary one that projects the spatial-part. The paper says "P(u) is the projection orthogonal to u in each tangent space (spatial projection with respect to u)." This would help those who would help to answer your question.

Comment: @robphy I've fixed that part now. Hopefully it works?

Comment: Your last expression has the form A=PB+A. (Since $\gamma$ is symmetric in its arguments, I'd drop the notation of its functional dependence....while you figure out the calculation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my answer ( https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/723077/148184 ) to your earlier question ( [Understanding where equation $2.3$ comes from?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/722890/understanding-where-equation-2-3-comes-from) ) here are some possibly useful relations:

- (essentially 2.2) $P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b \stackrel{\tiny (-+++)}{\equiv} (\delta^a{}_b + u^a u_b)$ implies $$\delta^a{}_b \stackrel{\tiny (-+++)}{\equiv} ( - u^a u_b) +P_{(u)}{}^a{}_b  $$
- (2.1c) $u'=u'_{\| u}+u'_{\perp u}= \gamma[ u + V_{(u',u)} ]$ implies that
  $$V_{(u',{\color{red}u})} \perp {\color{red}u} \qquad\mbox{note the second argument is ${\color{red}u}$}$$
- Thus, $$P_{({\color{red}u})}V_{(u',{\color{red}u})}=V_{(u',{\color{red}u})}$$
  and similarly
  $$P_{(u')}V_{(u,u')}=V_{(u,u')}$$
  but
  $$P_{(u)}V_{(u,u')}=-\gamma V_{(u',u)}$$
  and similarly
  $$P_{(u')}V_{(u',u)}=-\gamma V_{(u,u')}.$$

So, following the top of p. 2553,
to get $V_{(U,u')}$, either

- use the $U$-equation in terms of $u'$ (2.1b), solve for $V_{(U,u')}$.
  to get $$V_{(U,u')}=\frac{1}{\gamma} U -u'$$
  *but this doesn't seem to make progress toward his equations.*
- or, instead, use the projection property
  $$V_{(U,u')}=P_{(u')}V_{(U,u')}$$
  which we write in index-notation as
  $$V_{(U,u')}^a=P_{(u')}{}^a{}_bV_{(U,u')}^b$$
  then use $\delta^a{}_b \stackrel{\tiny (-+++)}{\equiv} ( - u^a u_b) +P_{(u)}
  {}^a{}_b  $ and the projection property
  \begin{align}
  V_{(U,u')}^a 
  &=\delta^a{}_c P_{(u')}{}^c{}_b V_{(U,u')}^b \\
  &={\color{red}{(-u^a{}u_c +P_{(u)}{}^a{}_c)}} P_{(u')}{}^c{}_b V_{(U,u')}^b\\
  &=-u^a{}u_c P_{(u')}{}^c{}_b V_{(U,u')}^b  +P_{(u)}{}^a{}_c P_{(u')}{}^c{}_b 
  V_{(U,u')}^b\\
  &=-u^a{}u_c  V_{(U,u')}^c \qquad\ +P_{(u)}{}^a{}_c P_{(u')}{}^c{}_b 
  V_{(U,u')}^b\\
  &=-u^a{}[u_c  V_{(U,u')}^c] \!\! \qquad + \quad P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_b 
  V_{(U,u')}^b
  \end{align}
  to get his first line.
  *It was the use of $P_{(u,u')}$ in the first line that led me in this direction!!*

Next, using (2.1d)
\begin{align}
&=-u^a{}[u_c  \qquad\ \qquad V_{(U,u')}^c]  +P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_b 
V_{(U,u')}^b\\
&=
-u^a{}[ \color{red}{\gamma (u'_c+V_{(u,u')}{}_c)}  V_{(U,u')}^c]  +P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_b 
V_{(U,u')}^b \qquad\mbox{gets his second line.}
\end{align}

Finally, by distributing
\begin{align}
&=
-u^a{}[ \color{red}{\gamma u'_c}V_{(U,u')}^c+ \color{red}{\gamma V_{(u,u')}{}_c}  V_{(U,u')}^c)]  +P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_b 
V_{(U,u')}^b\\
&=
-u^a{}[ {\qquad 0\quad}+ \color{red}{\gamma V_{(u,u')}{}_c}  V_{(U,u')}^c)]  +P_{(u,u')}{}^a{}_b 
V_{(U,u')}^b
\end{align}
we get his third line, Eq. (2.8).